# How do I filter get_the_excerpt() but keep all of its functionality intact?

Tags: filters, excerpt

I have a custom meta field that I want to display as my excerpt. I use a filter that does this for me:

```
add_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', function($output){
  $output=get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'my_meta_field', true);
  return $output;
});
```

Now whenever I use `get_the_excerpt()` or `the_excerpt()` inside of the loop I get the content of `my_meta_field`.

But since WP 4.5.0 [`get_the_excerpt()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_excerpt/) accepts a Post ID or WP_Post object as parameter. I would like to keep this functionality intact while using my filter.

So imagine I want to use `get_the_excerpt()` outside of the loop. When I call `get_the_excerpt(1234)` (1234 being the ID of a post) I get the wrong excerpt back because the `get_the_ID()` in my filter grabs whatever `global $post` has to offer at that moment.

What is the most elegant / efficient way to solve this? Can I somehow use the ID I am passing to get_the_excerpt inside my filter? Or do I need to create a mini loop and set `global $post` to `get_post(1234)`?

Comment: the problem that I had with the filter the last time I looked was that if you use `the_excerpt` it is the only one that gets the post id, while the rest of the filters (I think the "more" was the main problem for me) that are being applied do not get it. Maybe I just looked wrong at the code back then, but I advice to test properly the full flow to make sure there are no unexpected surprises.

Answer (score 2):

In spite of what the Codex says, since WP 4.5, where the addition of the post argument to the function get_the_excerpt was added, this filter takes two arguments. The second argument is the post object whose excerpt you are manipulating.

So the function still works in the loop without an explicit post, we make the second argument optional.

```
add_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', 'wpse_242462_excerpt_filter' );

function wpse_242462_excerpt_filter( $excerpt, $post = null ){

      if ( $post ) {
        $ID = $post->ID;
      } else {
        $ID = get_the_ID();
      }

      $excerpt = get_post_meta( $ID, 'wpse_242462_meta_field', true);

      return $excerpt;
});
```

Hopefully it goes without saying that you need to substitute whatever meta key you are already using.

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: Just have :-)  I was on my phone before, just switched to laptop to type up the code.

Comment: Hopefully you spotted the error in my code, where I completely missed out the function name!  Now corrected.

Comment: Now when I use `get_the_excerpt()` inside the loop I get a bunch of warnings and notices and no output. `Warning: Missing argument 2`, `Notice: Undefined variable: post`, `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object`.

Comment: Ah. Needs a conditional check on $post in case it's not set. I'll be back on a proper keyboard in a couple of hours.

Comment: That should fix it.

Comment: off topic comment, I really hate when local variables are named "$post" as you can never be sure with a quick look if it is the global one

Comment: Fair point @MarkKaplun, I probably just used whatever is listed in the WP core source comment on the filter without thinking about it.  I'll just absorb the hate and diffuse it into code-lurve.

Answer (score -1):

Even if you're not in the loop, if you're on within a post or page (or other post type) generated from WordPress, $post will be set.  So if you just replace `get_the_ID()` in your function above with `$post->ID`, it will work.  If you've been running other queries on the page, you may need to run `wp_reset_query();` to get the actual post ID.

If you want to pass a specific post, you need to separate the function from the add_filter call along the lines of:

```
// function to pass the ID to
function my_meta_excerpt($postID){
  $output=get_post_meta($postID, 'my_meta_field', true);
  return $output;
}
// add filter call
add_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', my_meta_excerpt);
```

Comment: The point of my question is that I do not want to use the global `post`. I want to use a post ID of my choice.

Comment: Let me update my answer

Comment: I'll try that! Might take a while though. Thanks!

Comment: The first argument passed by the filter is an excerpt, not a post ID.